# Trying to install OpenCL on VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, opencl, ubuntu-14.04

PC Config:
AMD Dual-core E-350 1.6Ghz
AMD 6310 HD Graphics Card

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware Player on top of Windows 8 and trying to figure out if i can run OpenCL on ubunutu ie using VM.

I was reading a manual of how to install OpenCL and the first step gives this output. Can someone see the output and tell me what i should do? Can i run OpenCL on VM?

1)First,we need to check our system configuration to determine whether it is possible to install      OpenCL in our machine. We can run the “Hardinfo” command on the terminal to get the complete summary of our system's configuration. If Hardinfo command is not installed in our system,then we can easily install it by the running the following command on the terminal: sudo apt-get install hardinfo
2)If our system can support OpenCL then we can go into the actual installation of OpenCL.
3)Download the Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications from [Intel's web site](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/). 
.....

```
varun@varun-virtual-machine:/$ hardinfo
```

The program 'hardinfo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install hardinfo

```
varun@varun-virtual-machine:/$ sudo apt-get install hardinfo

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
```

You might want to run '`apt-get -f install`' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
fglrx : Depends: fglrx-core but it is not installable
         Recommends: fglrx-amdcccle but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: No hardware-accelerated OpenCL in virtual machines (unless you can do PCI-passthrough to pass your GPU to the VM, and even then it's not reliable).

Comment: So i should just dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, that's a better idea.

Answer (score 6):

Since Ubuntu 18.04, all you need to get a version of OpenCL running on a CPU-only environment like a VM is:

```
sudo apt-get install libpocl2
```

Then `clinfo` will tell you, for example:

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
  Platform Vendor                                 The pocl project
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 pocl 1.4, None+Asserts, LLVM 9.0.1, RELOC, SLEEF, DISTRO, POCL_DEBUG
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             POCL

  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
  Device Vendor                                   GenuineIntel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x6c636f70
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 pocl HSTR: pthread-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-skylake
  Driver Version                                  1.4
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 pocl
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               8
  Max clock frequency                             2807MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     8
    Supported partition types                     equally, by counts
    Supported affinity domains                    (n/a)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             4096x4096x4096
  Max work group size                             4096
  Preferred work group size multiple              8
  Preferred / native vector sizes
    char                                                16 / 16
    short                                               16 / 16
    int                                                  8 / 8
    long                                                 4 / 4
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                8 / 8
    double                                               4 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              24638332928 (22.95GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           8589934592 (8GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        6291456 (6MiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            536870912 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               4194304 (4MiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        4194304 (4MiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
  printf() buffer size                            16777216 (16MiB)
  Built-in kernels                                (n/a)
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Portable Computing Language
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [POCL]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [POCL]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.11
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
```

Tested:

- [WSL Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) 20.04 on Windows
- Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 on [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) (Azure VMs)

Many thanks to the [PoCL team](http://portablecl.org/) for making this possible!

Comment: Thanks, the `sudo apt-get install libpocl2` was absolutely critical!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to run OpenCL in a virtual machine, but you will only have access to the CPU device.
The Intel SDK will not work, because it has strict hardware requirements, but the AMD SDK installs fine. I am running with AMD-APP-SDK-v2.8-RC-lnx64 on a Ubuntu 14.04 VM under Windows 8 + VirtualBox. You can get the SDK from here: http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/download-archive/

Comment: We won't be able to use GPU's in the device ??

Comment: @sathis In a consumer/desktop VM environment - no. I wrote this some time ago, so I don't know what the latest state of affairs is, but I know that some server VM products support "GPU passthrough".